# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, warnings

I have a problem with my PHP code.

I am trying to write a code, that should find the information of an email for example which are only like mike@mike.com".

if I'm running the code, I'm getting the error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .......

here is my code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');

$db = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE email = mike@mike.com ";
    
foreach ($pdo->query($db) as $row) {

   echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."<br />";
   echo "E-Mail: ".$row['email']."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM request WHERE email = mike@mike.com` isn't a valid SQL query. You'd need quotes around the e-mail address.

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php); A nice feature of PDO::query() is that it enables you to iterate over the rowset returned by a **successfully** executed SELECT statement.

Comment: omg ok i just forgot  '  '  this :))) Thanks